# Call the same handler with different selectors which return the same HTML object

Tags: jquery, html

Is an event handler bound to an element, so you can trigger the event with different selectors? Look the example below to see what I want to know:

Example:
HTML

```
<ul id="itemsList">
<li class="items" id="item1">element1</li>
<li class="items" id="item2">element2</li>
<li class="items" id="item3">element3</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript in which click event handler is defined:

```
$('.items').click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

To invoque this handler I think it's possible to do in several ways, using different selectors, therefore `$('#item1').click();` and `$(#itemsList li).eq(1).click();` would call the same event handler. Right?
If yes I'm certainly doing something wrong because it's not working properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few things to point out:

- Don't forget `"` in the expression `$(#itemsList li).eq(1).click();`
- `.eq(1)` actually selects second `li`, because [eq index](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) starts at 0.

Correct syntax:

```
// define handler
$('.items').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text() + " clicked");
});

// call handler
$('#item1').click() ;

$("#itemsList li").eq(0).click();
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NUBFj/1/)

Comment: Which I want is to call the same handler using different selectors not defining handlers for each selector.

Comment: And of course the handler needs to be defined before the lines in which it's invoked, right?

Answer (score 0):

Calling .click() with no arguments or .trigger('click') should call the click event handler on the results of your selector. As pinouchon has pointed out be careful with your selector syntax, using quotes where appropriate and remembering that .eq() is zero-indexed meaning that .eq(1) will select the second li element.

Ultimately, to call the event handler I think what you want is:

```
$('#itemsList li').eq(0).click();
```

Or indeed,

```
$('#item1').click();
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've used this way to call click handler many times and seems to work OK

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct, according to http://api.jquery.com/click/ it can also be used to trigger the event handler when no arguments are passed. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you already do invokes this handler:
http://jsfiddle.net/a3tNM/

`$('#item1').click();` and `$(#itemsList li).eq(1).click();` Would not call the same handler. It creates a new one.